# How to fetch existing JSON that exists in data-attr and update that

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the given fiddle , click on Addons buttons and on selection and unselection 
of  Checkboxes , i am trying to update the data-attr 
array present as data-stuff .

Once i set the data how can i fetch the existing and update it with new data .
http://jsfiddle.net/kgm9o693/9/

```
// checkbox checked
$(document).on('click', '.ui-checkbox-off', function (event) {
    var vendoritemsdata = $(".lastItm_Wrap").data('stuff');
    var checkboxid = $(this).next().attr("id");
    var cost = $(this).attr("cost");
    var toppcrusts = [];
    toppcrusts.push({
        'name': checkboxid,
            'cost': cost
    });
    if (vendoritemsdata.length == 0) {
        $('.lastItm_Wrap').attr('data-stuff', toppcrusts);
    } 
    else {
        var existingdata = $('.lastItm_Wrap').data('data-stuff');
    }
});
```

Could you please tell me how to resolve this ??

Comment: clicking add-ons, nothing shows up in FF . I see it using Chrome. Still not sure what objective is though

Comment: okay , What ever has been checked i am creating a JSON and want to update that to the existing data-stuff

Comment: Extending the existing? Suggest you write out the whole process flow for all the data storage on element in the question Not clear what expected results are and what's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the DOM as a variable. It should be the other way around. Use the DOM only to show results (total cost in your case). But before that keep everything into an array serialize the array if you need it as json or data-stuff.

Examine the example at the bottom of this http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

If you want to keep doing it your way, convert the data to JSON and use this:

**Set data**

```
$('.lastItm_Wrap').attr('data-stuff', JSON.stringify(toppcrusts) );
```

**Get data**

```
var existingdata = JSON.parse( $('.lastItm_Wrap').attr('data-stuff') );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kgm9o693/12/